# Are there known and interesting or easy examples of groups $G$ which admit $\mathbb Z$ as a distorted normal subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

A finitely generated subgroup $H$ of $G$ is said to be *un*distorted if any word metric on $H$ and any metric on $H$ induced by a word metric of $G$ are roughly equivalent (i.e., they differ by a multiplicative and additive constant; in other words, $H \hookrightarrow G$ is a quasi-isometric embedding). It is said to be distorted otherwise.

Baumslag–Solitar groups $G = \langle a, b \,|\, aba^{-1} = b^n \rangle$ provide easy example of groups $G$ with distorted, infinite cyclic, *non*-normal subgroups $H$.  I was wondering how difficult it is to find examples of groups with distorted, infinite cyclic, *normal* subgroups.

Comment: You mean Baumslag-Solitar gives examples of *distorted* infinite cyclic non-normal subgroups, right?

Comment: Just an observation: if there is a distorted cyclic normal subgroup, $\langle a\rangle$, then $gag^{-1}=a^{\pm 1}$ for each $g\in G$ (otherwise you contradict the cyclicity). The centralizer of $a$ is then either all of $G$ or an index 2 subgroup.

Comment: correct (and you don't need the distorsion for this)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained by A. Sisto [here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~alsisto/LectureNotesGGT.pdf) on p.20 and p.21, "The  subgroup  generated  by
$z$
in  the  Heisenberg  group
$$〈
x,y,z
|
[
x,y
]  =
z,
[
x,z
] = [
y,z
] = 1
〉$$
is isomorphic to
$\mathbf Z$
and distorted." As $\langle z \rangle$ is the center of the Heisenberg group and hence normal, this gives one example.

Comment: I agree with you and sisto.

Comment: Distortion in nilpotent groups is a classical subject. From work of Guivarch (1973) and possibly earlier, if $G$ is finitely generated nilpotent, torsion-free, and $G^i$ is its lower central series, and $x\in G^i-G^{i+1}$ then $|x^n|\simeq n^{1/i}$. In particular, if $G$ is $c$-step nilpotent (that is $G^{c+1}=\{1\}$ and $x\in G^c$, then $x$ is central and hence you get many examples. Also taking a suitable semidirect product of the Heisenberg group and $\mathbf{Z}$, you can get a exponentially distorted central cyclic subgroup.

Comment: thanks! 

Here it is a beautiful illustration of the Cayley graph of the Heisenberg group:

https://conan777.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/c-c-3.jpg

The vertical direction is "z", the left-right is x, while the diagonal one is y. The red path is xyx^{-1}y^{-1}.